# Express req object is not defined inside async sequelilze js then call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lambda, mean-stack

I am new to express js. I am working on a project. where i have to send email when the user is updated. but the problem is that once the user is updated. Inside the update success I don't have access to req object or userUpdate. I know its a concept issue. Can you please let me know how to fix this.?
thanks

```
module.exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'clinic_id', 'profile_id');
    if (!_.isString(body.email) || !_.isString(body.first_name) || body.email.length == 0 || body.first_name.length == 0) {
        res.status(404).send();
    } else {
        var userUpdate = req.body;
        var selector = {
            email: userUpdate.email
        };
        userUpdate.updatedAt = new Date().getTime();
        //*********req object and userUpdate have data till this point**************//

        db.user.update(userUpdate, { where: selector })
            .then(function(result) {
                // ****req object and userUpdate are not defined here. WHY??

                mailer.sendActivateEmail(result);
                // sending response to front end
                res.json(result);
            }).catch(function(e) {
                res.status(500).json(e);
                console.log("error updating user:", e);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: " I don't have access to req object or userUpdate." how do you check this?

Comment: Are you using mongodb native driver ?

Comment: no i am using sequelize js with postgres

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my understanding. I am able to access req object anywhere in the function. The problem occurs in debugging. When i use debugger in my code. I usually don't have access to variables outside of function scope.
When i use console.log to print object before debugger, things work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Don't have time to actually run your code but I would suggest two things:

1. Try binding your function call so that the function definitely receives the req object.

   ```
   db.user.update(userUpdate, { where: selector }).then(updateSuccess.bind(req)))
   ```

   Define `updateSuccess` like this

   ```
   const updateSuccess = (req, result) => { ... }
   ```
2. Try using anonymous functions instead of `function`, ie.

   ```
   module.exports.update = (req, res) => {
   ```

   Could be some weird scoping problem

Comment: How do think this would help? What is "weird scoping problem"? This looks like a random changes to a code :)

Comment: Variables are hoisted so they could be reassigned elsewhere.

Comment: And how this is related to the problem? `req` - is a function argument. Which line do you think reassigns `req`? There is no attempts to reassign it or shadow it with a new variable in the code provided.

Comment: `req` could potentially be reassigned outside the code provided, that's why I mentioned hoisting.

Comment: Modified - yes, but not reassigned. Of course assuming OP provided full function body.

Comment: @AlexHarley i get req is not defined inside .then() so binding it won't help